# Laravel Pluck - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I need to select the id and name field, pass the collection to the view and iterate over it to generate options for a select. However, I am getting the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object 
>   (View: ../resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
>   (View: ../resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $propertyTypes = PropertyType::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('home', compact('propertyTypes'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach($propertyTypes as $propertyType)
    <option value="{{ $propertyType->id }}">
        {{ $propertyType->name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Table

```
ID  Name
1   Detached
2   Semi-detached
3   Terraced
4   Flat
5   Bungalow
6   Land
7   Park Home
```

Comment: You'll need `@foreach($propertyTypes as $id => $name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `pluck` method to get the results as `key-value` pair but in your view you're trying to access the value as an object which is causing this error.

Either you've to fetch your results as models or you've to update your view.

**Option 1:** Fetch results as models

```
public function index()
{
    $propertyTypes = PropertyType::select('name', 'id')->get();
    return view('home', compact('propertyTypes'));
}
```

**Option 2:** Iterate over collection as key-value

```
@foreach($propertyTypes as $id => $name)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">
        {{ $name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Try just:

```
public function index()
{
    $propertyTypes = PropertyType::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('home', ['propertyTypes' => $propertyTypes]);
}
```

If not work You have to check your `view` for example:

`views/ControllerName/blog/index.blade.php`

Exists this `blade` or Not?

Because your `stack trace` wrote in `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

This will give you the required collection to iterate through.

```
public function index()
{
    $propertyTypes = PropertyType::select('name', 'id')->get();
    return view('home', compact('propertyTypes'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View

```
@foreach($propertyTypes as $id => $name)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">
        {{ $name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

now why we need to do like this. if you print your object dd($propertyTypes->tooArray()); like this you will see an array containing id column value as array index. so to get this value you need to store the index value somewhere, during foreach I use $id => $name so the $id will get index value and $name will get data of that index which is name column value